# Foursquare integration in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am trying to do the FourSquare integration in iPhone..i couldn't found any good guidelines through Goggling.... Can any one suggest me the Good guidelines or URLs for FourSquare integration in iPhone..

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the foursquare [api link](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-API-v2/tree/master/Foursquare2-iOS)

Example of Foursquare [integration link](https://github.com/anka/bw_examples/tree/master/FoursquareIntegration).

Further code for Foursquare integration

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Foursquare";
    //check the authentication
    if ([Foursquare2 isNeedToAuthorize]) {
       //If needed show the webview 
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?display=touch&client_id=%@&response_type=code&redirect_uri=%@",OAUTH_KEY,REDIRECT_URL];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
        [webView setDelegate:self];
        [self.view addSubview:webView];
        [webView release];
        mTableView.hidden = YES;
    }else{
        //Show your view
        mTableView.hidden = NO;
        [Foursquare2 searchVenuesNearByLatitude:@"40.763" longitude:@"-73.990" accuracyLL:nil altitude:nil accuracyAlt:nil query:@"" limit:@"15" intent:@"" callback:^(BOOL success, id result){
            if (success) {

                tableData = [[FoursquareParser parseSearchVenuesResultsDictionary:(NSDictionary*)result] retain];
                [mTableView reloadData];

            }
        }];

    }
}
```